# Python: generating a tree using "yield"

Tags: python, yield, python-itertools

I am trying to set up a system to generate a set of "configurations".
These configurations are simple key/value pairs stored in a python dict.

These configurations are the result of transforming the dict with a sequence of function, this is what i call a workflow.

Here is a simple example of what I ended up with:

```
global_data = [dict()]

def workflow_step1(data):
    results = []
    for i in range(1,4):
        data['key'] = i
        results.append(copy.deepcopy(data))
    return results

def workflow_step2(data):
    results = []
    for i in range(1,3):
        data['otherkey'] = i
        results.append(copy.deepcopy(data))
    return results

def workflow_step3(data):
    data['yetanotherkey'] = 42
    return [copy.deepcopy(data)]

def list_workflow():
    return [workflow_step1, workflow_step2, workflow_step3]

def merge(lhs,rhs):
    return lhs+rhs

def run(data):
    for step in list_workflow():
        data = reduce(lambda lhs, rhs: lhs+rhs, [step(d) for d in data])
    return data

print run(global_data)
```

This works kind of well, i get:

```
[{'yetanotherkey': 42, 'otherkey': 1, 'key': 1},
 {'yetanotherkey': 42, 'otherkey': 2, 'key': 1},
 {'yetanotherkey': 42, 'otherkey': 1, 'key': 2},
 {'yetanotherkey': 42, 'otherkey': 2, 'key': 2},
 {'yetanotherkey': 42, 'otherkey': 1, 'key': 3},
 {'yetanotherkey': 42, 'otherkey': 2, 'key': 3}]
```

As you can see, the goal is to obtain all possible combinations of the dict. Each step of the workflow returns a set of possible combinations, that should create a new branch of possibilities for the upcoming steps.

The problem that I am facing, is that the users are now creating more and more workflow steps, thus leading to a combinatorial explosion.

The problem in my naive design, is that i generate the whole tree of all posibilities at once.

I was hoping to resolve this using `yield` and generators, to generate one possibility at a time, and thus not store everything at the same time.

I was of course able to rewrite the workflow step using yield:

```
def workflow_step1(data):
    for i in range(1,4):
        data['key'] = i
        yield copy.deepcopy(data)

def workflow_step2(data):
    for i in range(1,3):
    data['otherkey'] = i
        yield copy.deepcopy(data)

def workflow_step3(data):
    data['yetanotherkey'] = 42
    yield copy.deepcopy(data)

def list_workflow():
    yield workflow_step1
    yield workflow_step2
    yield workflow_step3
```

But I just can't make my brain to think of the way to rewrite the `run` function to process each step sequentially. I get lost in a brainmaze of yields and generators.

Any ideas are more that welcome!

Comment: You probably can write `run()` the same way you did previously.

Answer (score 3):

I think `itertools.product` will do exactly what you want. Here's an approach that returns a generator that yields one combination of your three steps at a time. Even if there are a lot more options in a single step, it won't take a huge amount of time or memory up front.

```
def step1():
    return [("key", i) for i in range(1,4)]

def step2():
    return [("otherkey", i) for i in range(1,3)]

def step3():
    return [("yetanotherkey", 42)]

def workflow_generator():
    return (dict(p) for p in itertools.product(step1(), step2(), step3()))
```

If you want to be able to handle a variable number of steps, you can modify things just slightly to make that work:

```
def workflow_generator(steps):
    return (dict(p) for p in itertools.product(*(step() for step in steps)))
```

Calling this version with `workflow_generator([step1, step2, step3])` will give the same results as the previous version, though you could assemble the arguments in some other way if you want (such as from a function).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your datastructures are messed up. The following code is just to give an idea (not fully operational in terms of your current structures). You should use trees basically and make a class like a workflow manager which registers steps. Steps are trees of steps. Use true id's instead of numbers.

Two suggestions

1.

```
import copy

global_data = [dict()]

class workflowManager:

    def __init__(self):
        self.steps = []
        self.data = list()

    def registerStep(self,step,stepNumber=1):
        for i in range(1,stepNumber+1):
            self.steps.append(step)

    def registerSubStep(self,step,substep):


    '''
    def hookToStep(self,step,hook):
        #find all steps
        indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(self.steps) if x == step]
        print 'hooking at ',indices
        for k in indices:
            a = self.steps[:k]
            b = self.steps[k:]
            self.steps = a + [hook] + b
    '''

    def performOnData(self):
        print 'self.data ',self.data
        for step in self.steps:
            print 'performing step ',step
            print 'data ',self.data
            self.data = step(self.data)

    def __str(self):
        return str(data)

def step1(data):
    lastn = 0
    try:
        lastn = data[-1]['key']
    except:
        pass
    data.append({'key': lastn+1})
    return data

def step2(data):
    lastn = 0
    try:
        lastn = data[-1]['otherkey']
    except:
        pass

    data.append({'otherkey': lastn+1})
    return data

def step3(data):
    data.append({'yetanotherkey': 42})
    return data


w = workflowManager()
w.step_register(step1,4)
#w.step_register(step2,3)
#w.step_register(step3,1)
w.hookToStep(step1,step3)

print w

w.performOnData()

print w
```

2.

```
class Step:

    def __init__(self,name,extra=None):
        self.steps = []
        self.name = name

    def addChild(self,child,repeat=1):
        for j in range(1,repeat+1):
            self.steps.append(child)

    def __str__(self):
        s = self.name + "\n"
        for sub in self.steps:
            s+=str(sub)
        return s


step1 = Step("yetanotherkey",42) #root
step2 = Step("otherkey")
step3 = Step("key")

step2.addChild(step3,2)
step1.addChild(step2,3)

print step1
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take the loops out of the `workflow_step` functions, and use `itertools.product` like this:

```
import copy
import itertools

def workflow_step1(data, param):
    data['key'] = param

def workflow_step2(data, param):
    data['otherkey'] = param

def workflow_step3(data, param):
    data['yetanotherkey'] = param

def list_workflow():
    return ([workflow_step1, workflow_step2, workflow_step3],
            [range(1,4),     range(1,3),     [42]])

def run(data):
    steps, param_lists = list_workflow()
    for params in itertools.product(*param_lists):
        d = copy.deepcopy(data)
        for step, param in zip(steps, params):
            step(d,param)
        yield d

for result in run({}):
    print result
```